# Adding rows in dataframe if they don't exist in another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I have 2 dataframes, `df1` & `df2`, in `df1` I have 5 weeks alone.

In `df2` I have the same column of **year/week** with a **product** column.

So if one of those rows in `df2` is not in `df1`, I'm looking for adding the **product** in that respectively **year/week**.

```
df1:
+----+-------------+
|    | year/week   |
+====+=============+
|  0 | 2022/01     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 2022/02     |
+----+-------------+
|  2 | 2022/03     |
+----+-------------+
|  3 | 2022/04     |
+----+-------------+
|  4 | 2022/05     |
+----+-------------+

df2:
+----+-------------+-----------+
|    | year/week   | product   |
+====+=============+===========+
|  0 | 2022/01     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2022/02     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  2 | 2022/01     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  3 | 2022/04     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  4 | 2022/05     | C         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

this is the expected output that I want to obtain, is there is a pythonic way to obtain this?

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
|    | year/week   | product   |
+====+=============+===========+
|  0 | 2022/01     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2022/02     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  2 | 2022/03     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  3 | 2022/04     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  4 | 2022/05     | A         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  5 | 2022/01     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  6 | 2022/02     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  7 | 2022/03     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  8 | 2022/04     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  9 | 2022/05     | B         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 10 | 2022/01     | C         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 11 | 2022/02     | C         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 12 | 2022/03     | C         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 13 | 2022/04     | C         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 14 | 2022/05     | C         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Cartesian product from the "year/week" column in `df1` and the unique "products" in `df2` and convert it into a DataFrame. You can omit `sort_values` if you don't particularly care about the order.

```
out = (pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['year/week'], df2['product'].unique()], 
                                 names=['year/week','product']).to_frame()
       .reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by='product', ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
   year/week product
0    2022/01       A
1    2022/02       A
2    2022/03       A
3    2022/04       A
4    2022/05       A
5    2022/01       B
6    2022/02       B
7    2022/03       B
8    2022/04       B
9    2022/05       B
10   2022/01       C
11   2022/02       C
12   2022/03       C
13   2022/04       C
14   2022/05       C
```